# 'Wood glue doesn't stick to wood glue'. Could this conventional wisdom be wrong?

Tags: technique, glue, adhesives

I've noticed something unexpected while testing PVA glues for strength.

**Glues tested**: Titebond Original, Titebond III Ultimate.

**Wood species**: Beech and Pine (and other unknown hardwood species).

Transverse to transverse grain joinery. All mating surfaces sandpapered.

**Control**: Glue applied evenly to both surfaces with brush then clamped straight away for 24h.

**Test 1**: Glue applied evenly to one surface with brush, then left to dry 1 hour. Then glue applied evenly to both surfaces before being clamped 24h.

**Test 2**: Glue applied to one surface with brush, excess glue scraped off with sandpaper (leaving surface moist), left to dry 1 hour. Glue applied evenly to both surfaces then clamped 24h.

I had expected the control joint to be stronger than test 2, and test 2 to be stronger than test 1.

In reality, the joints would seem to be equally resistant to sheer stress and longitudinal traction. All joints had barely visible glue lines, the difference between test 1 and the others is in the range of microns suggesting most of the dried glue had been absorbed into the wood during clamping.

The results seem to be reproducible, meaning this could have implications for correcting errors in assembly, or repairs and maintenance of cured glue joints.

Do you think this is unusual, given what we know about how PVA glues work?

Comment: what is the "conventional wisdom" that this goes against?

Comment: I use a glue that after applying to both surfaces is “work” dry after 1 hour and fully dry after 24 - gets the job done without loosing 23 hours...

Comment: It looks like you are proposing two methods that take more work than the “control” but get the same result. What implications would this have?

Comment: As pointed out in the Q, the implications are for repairs, maintenance on joints that have failed. Also, for how much time you're permitted to reassemble your joints when you make an error during joinery.

Comment: The only glue that I put down and let dry is rubber cement. All normal wood glued I coat clamp and am done , I am not sure where your conventional wisdom came from but this is how my dad taught me and he was a master carpenter (my brother still has the desk he made that passed including hidden spaces).

Comment: "*In reality, the joints would seem to be equally resistant to sheer stress and longitudinal traction.*"  You have scientific equipment that measures that ? How do you plan to effect the entire woodworking industry with your findings ?

Comment: Yes the conventional wisdom is wrong, *for a given definition of wrong* (details matter). As for your tests, what are the actual strength results you got? The key thing to remember in anything like this is exactly what you're aiming to match — match only, you cannot exceed it — so unless you are matching the strength of glues used normally the results are really of limited to no value in practical circumstances. Regardless of this, if your results are of equal strength then you're not clamping hard enough, simple as that (i.e. you're not achieving the *maximum* possible strength from the PVA).

Comment: Your testing methodology has exposed a flaw, as you suggest in your own answer. PVA glues, _once cured_ will tend to not form a good bond with fresh PVA glue. A full cure is dependent on a number of factors you might be able to control for, but 1 hour is probably not long enough under most conditions.

Comment: There very well may be some conditions where the received wisdom does not hold true, but these wisdoms are often practical simplifications in a complicated world. I'd look to what folks who do a lot of regluing have to say about practical experience. Furniture restorers and luthiers have a lot of experience with a variety of glues, and how to glue up previous glued surfaces. I know most guitar makers would remove cured PVA from surfaces if they wanted a guitar not to fold up in half under stress.

Comment: @Market12 You start out strong with the scientific method, but fall flat on objective data. To reiterate what Graphis is saying: The strongest possible bond with PVA is most consistently achieved by following conventional wisdom. It is possible that you matched the strength of that bond, but more likely have a weaker bond that is acceptable for your needs. Without an objective measure of when the joint fails (e.g. hanging weights until failure, or some more advanced setup), then you cannot claim they are equally strong bonds.

Comment: I suspect that 1) conventional wisdom is correct, and also 2) what you found is true insofar as the joint is "strong enough", and 3) often we don't need the strongest possible glue joint. This is true a lot in woodworking; we don't need the "best" joint, we only need one that is good enough. Or said another way, what is "best" is dependent on context. All other things being equal, you want the strongest glue joint possible. You definitely want one that won't fail in use! Whether your method achieves that, I don't know. It might! I don't think that invalidates conventional wisdom, though.

Comment: You've, um, missed my point entirely. The desired strength for glued wood joints is for them to be strong enough *not to be able to be separated*, either in sheer or by directly pulling them apart. While you might achieve 'acceptable' strength going another route it's not as strong, and max strength is what to aim for. Much of woodworking is about overbuilding for strength, to get things to hold up long term, and to withstand unusual (but possible) overloading situations as e.g. when people lean back in chairs, move heavily laden tables over uneven flooring. [contd]

Comment: It's in those sorts of situations where sub-par glue joints *can and do fail*. And PVA bonding to PVA is sub par, have no illusions about that. I won't debate the point any further as we can't get into extended discussions here (it's specifically against the rules). But if you want to get into a debate about this post to any of the established forums, as long as you're prepared for the pushback you'll receive ^_^

Comment: @Market12 While no one has explicitly requested the data, the request was implied by multiple comments from multiple users. I was merely commenting that the lack of objective data does not allow for an objective comparison of bond strength. If you have objective data about the bond strength and can share it, I think that would greatly help your readers and potential responses to your question. No ill will intended and I think it’s great if your observations can help someone. I for one am curious about the results as an amateur woodworker.

Comment: @statueuphemism I think it's only you and graphus asking for data, which is pointless if your comments presume 'a priori' that it is wrong. Sadly, I didn't record the results because it was comparative strength I was examining on an anecdotal basis rather than doing quantitative testing for Titebond. But recorded results wouldn't have made the data any more objective. What you need, ultimately, are enough data points to plot confidence intervals for results that are examinable under peer review

Comment: I think folks here are unclear what you want from this question. Your test is (as you have already guessed) flawed for the purpose of ad hoc "are these two joints relatively the same strength, where strength is used in the most general sense". There is plenty of evidence out there with load and shear data, and everyone recognizes that this is not reasonable for the layperson to reproduce. Since your test is pretty much invalid, the everyday maxim that "PVA will not stick well to cured PVA" is still true as much as it ever was. Whether or not it is strong enough for an application...

Comment: We already have what we want from the question, which is an answer and a plausible explanation. Also, anecdotal testing is inductively valid. If only 5-sigma statistical data is valid evidence, things like case reports in medical peer-reviewed literature would be of no evidentiary value.

Comment: @Market12 It's unclear to me why you seem to think this Q&A is somehow demanding non-anecdotal evidence. Most comments tacitly agreed that in practice all sorts of results could be observed and that few here are in a position to do much other than provide anecdotal evidence. You did get a lot of X-Y responses because practice tells us that when a joint really counts, you should follow the common practice of assuming PVA will not make the best joint in the case you describe.

Comment: That being said, some understood you were questioning some practical advice with a test, but then you immediately saw that the methodology was almost certainly a problem -- this is only what I mean by flawed. It isn't the anecdotal part of the test that was the problem. In this regard, this Q&A is a success. At the end of the day, this isn't about anyone demanding some perfect test on your part. To the contrary, it was about not knowing exactly what was expected as an answer. I suppose the cleverest among us would have seen that your test needed days, not hours.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107923/discussion-between-market12-and-jdv).

Comment: Titebond is an aliphatic resin emulsion which is different than PVA (white glues). I don't know about whether it can stick to it or not but you are correct about PVAs which is good to know~

Comment: @anthony (This comment was provided by Graphus and coppied here): Titebond, and all other yellow carpenter's glues, are versions of PVA, with yellow dye added! "Aliphatic resin emulsion" is just another way of describing the chemistry (there are others). Over here and in other markets overseas the water-resistant and waterproof version of PVA are frequently left white, and while some are described in yet another way a few are simply called PVA on the labelling.

Comment: I have found a great way to bond cement based products to smooth wood using a method similar to what you’re exploring. First apply a layer of wood glue and let it dry for an hour or so, then apply another layer of wood glue and allow it to semi-dry only ten minutes or so. While that is drying prepare the cement and pour it in the semi-dry glue. The bond is quite robust. In my experience better than using surface primers.

Answer (score 4):

In the absence of helpful comments, I've done some research on PVA glue chemistry to see what this could be. The general rule of thumb is that wood glue does not stick to cured wood glue.

Wood glue binding undergoes two phases.

1. A short-term drying phase (< 2 hr), during which the material is simply dehydrated.
2. A curing phase (24 h+), in which electrostatic and covalent cross-links are formed.

[image: Source: Ülker O (2016). Wood Adhesives and Bonding Theory. DOI: 10.5772/65759]

I'm no expert on PVA glues, but what I'm observing could be as simple as partially dried surface glue being mobilized again through re-wetting before cross-linking occurs.

This would then allow it to be absorbed into wood or cross-link with glue on the adjacent surface.

Comment: Also, make sure you provide a reference for that image.